# Как сделать 3 конструктора с одинаковой сигнатурой?

Tags: c#, перегрузка-операторов

Нужно написать программу, содержащую класс `Triangle`. В данном классе должно быть три конструктора:

1. Конструктор, принимающий три стороны.
2. Конструктор, принимающий две стороны и угол между ними и рассчитывающий третью сторону по теореме косинусов.
3. Конструктор, принимающий два угла и сторону между ними и рассчитывающий оставшиеся стороны по теореме синусов (памятуя о теореме о сумме углов треугольника).

Каждый `Triangle` также должен возвращать собственную площадь.

То есть имеем следующее:

```
class Triangle
{
    Triangle(double side1, double side2, double side3)
    {
    }
    Triangle(double side1, double side2, double angle)
    {
    }
    Triangle(double side1, double angle1, double angle2)
    {
    }
}
```

**Вся проблема в том, что у всех трех конструкторов одинаковая сигнатура, но разная логика.

Вопрос: как решить эту проблему "правильно"?**

"Неправильные" варианты:

1. Замена параметра(ов) `double` на `string` и дальнейший парсинг `string` в `double`.
2. Замена параметра(ов) `double` на `float`.
3. Вынесение параметров в массив:

   ```
   Triangle(double[] sides, double angle)
   ```
4. Создание нового типа данных `Angle`.

Comment: Ура, один из немногих вопросов, где спрашивается, как решить правильно, а не как решить быстро/коротко/на тяп-ляп.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Вариант 1 - используйте именованные конструкторы.

Именованным конструктором называется статический метод, задача которого - создать объект с заданными параметрами. Иногда их еще не вполне корректно называют фабричными методами.

```
class Triangle
{
    private Triangle() {}

    public static Triangle From3Sides(double side1, double side2, double side3) { ... }

    public static Triangle From2SidesAndAngle(double side1, double side2, double angle) { ... }

    public static Triangle FromSideAnd2Angles(double side, double angle1, double angle2) { ... }
}
```

### Вариант 2 - использовать доменные типы данных

Определяем типы данных "длина" и "угол" - и используем их в конструкторах.

```
class Length
{
  public double Value { get; }

  public Length() {}
  public Length(double value) { Value = value; }

  public static implicit operator double (Length length)
    => length.Value;
  public static implicit operator Length (double value)
    => new Length(value);
}

class Angle
{
  public double Value { get; }

  public Angle() {}
  public Angle(double value) { Value = value; }

  public static implicit operator double (Angle angle)
    => angle.Value;
  public static implicit operator Angle (double value)
    => new Angle(value);
}
```

Comment: Я бы использовал одновременно оба подхода. Одной только строгой типизации может оказаться недостаточно: вдруг вам нужен треугольник по трём сторонам и по трём медианам?

Comment: @VladD три медианы не являются стандартным признаком равенства треугольников - а потому построение треугольника по трем медианам уже не будет задачей конструктора :)

Comment: Ну, два катета и катет с гипотенузой — более распространённый сюжет. Или там катет и прилежащий угол против катета и противолежащего угла.

Comment: @VladD это все способы задания прямоугольных треугольников, в треугольниках общего вида нет никаких катетов и гипотенуз.

Comment: Да, конечно, я не о данном частном случае. Я привёл пример проблемы из той же предметной области, которая не решается одной лишь типизацией (в разумном смысле понятия «типизация»). То, что в частном случае можно формально обойтись без именованных конструкторов — случайная подробность конкретной частной задачи, на мой вкус.

Comment: А откуда термин `Доменный тип данных`?

Comment: @alexolut чаще всего его можно видеть в теории реляционных БД, но пару раз видел и в других областях. Откуда он родом точно - не скажу.

Comment: Я сначала подумал, что это какой-то шарповый.

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант сгруппировать наборы параметров в структуры:

```
public struct ThreeSides
{
    double side1;
    double side2;
    double side3;
}
public struct TwoSidesAndAngle
{
    double side1;
    double side2;
    double angle;
}
public struct SideAndTwoAngles
{
    double side1;
    double angle1;
    double angle2;
}

public class Triangle
{
    public Triangle(ThreeSides params)
    {
    }

    public Triangle(TwoSidesAndAngle params)
    {
    }

    public Triangle(SideAndTwoAngles params)
    {
    }
}
```

но мне кажется более правильный вариант с фабриками в ответе Павла

Answer (score 1):

Пара альтернативных вариантов к уже предложенным.

Т.к. выбор перегруженной функции (и конструктора в том числе) осуществляется на основании типов, понятно, что создать несколько разных конструкторов с одинаковыми сигнатурами не получится.

Проблему можно решить путем добавления дополнительного параметра.

1. Заводятся новые "пустые" классы (имена взял из ответа @Argon):

   ```
   class ThreeSides {}
   class TwoSidesAndAngle {}
   class SideAndTwoAngles {}
   ```

   Сигнатуры конструкторов в этом случае будут следующие:

   ```
   Triangle(double side1, double side2, double side3, ThreeSides unused);
   Triangle(double side1, double side2, double angle, TwoSidesAndAngle unused);
   Triangle(double side1, double angle1, double angle2, SideAndTwoAngles unused);
   ```
2. Используется перечисление `enum`.

   ```
   enum Kind { ThreeSides, TwoSidesAndAngle, SideAndTwoAngles }
   ```

   В этом случае конструктор будет единственный с ветвлением логики внутри:

   ```
   Triangle(double arg1, double arg2, double arg3, Kind kind);
   ```

   При этом для аргумента `kind` можно задать значение по умолчанию, если планируется, что будет преобладать тот или иной вариант построения треугольника. Например:

   ```
   Triangle(double arg1, double arg2, double arg3, Kind kind = Kind.ThreeSides);
   ```

Comment: В варианте с пустыми классами красивее наследовать их от `Triangle` и определять конструктор внутри :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov наследование в принципе даст возможность выбирать тип в динамике, как и с `enum`. С другой стороны, для уже построенных треугольников истинный тип должен быть одинаковым. Т.е. желательно не позволять создавать производные треугольники.

Answer (score 0):

При желании можно вытворить что-то такое:

http://ideone.com/XLf5Pz

```
using System;

class Triangle
{
    public struct NeverCreateMe {}

    public Triangle(double side1, double side2, double side3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("3 sides");
    }

    public Triangle(double side1, double side2, NeverCreateMe ignored = default(NeverCreateMe), double angle = 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("2 sides and 1 angle");
    }

    public Triangle(double side1, NeverCreateMe ignored = default(NeverCreateMe), double angle1 = 0, double angle2 = 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1 side and 2 angles");
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var a = new Triangle(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
        var b = new Triangle(1.0, 2.0, angle: 3.0);
        var c = new Triangle(1.0, angle1: 2.0, angle2: 3.0);
    }
}
```

Или даже такое:

http://ideone.com/VEGn2s

```
using System;

class Triangle
{
    public struct NeverCreateMe<T> {}

    public Triangle(double side1, double side2, double side3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("3 sides");
    }

    public Triangle(double side1, double side2, double angle, NeverCreateMe<bool> ignored = default(NeverCreateMe<bool>))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("2 sides and 1 angle");
    }

    public Triangle(double side1, double angle1, double angle2, NeverCreateMe<int> ignored = default(NeverCreateMe<int>))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1 side and 2 angles");
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var a = new Triangle(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
        var b = new Triangle(1.0, 2.0, angle: 3.0);
        var c = new Triangle(1.0, angle1: 2.0, angle2: 3.0);
    }
}
```

У каждого способа есть свои плюсы и минусы, но при желании их можно решить.