# Перегрузки конструктора с опциональными параметрами C#

Tags: c#

Допустим есть класс `Myclass`, имеющий 3 конструктора - первый по умолчанию, без параметров, и два таких:

```
public Myclass(string param1, string param2 = null)
{
    Text = param1;
    Data = param2;
}

public Myclass(string param1, string param3, string param2 = null)
{
    Text = param1;
    Url = param3;
    Data = param2;
}
```

Сигнатура разная (*или нет?*), но какой конструктор будет вызван в таком случае

```
new Myclass("param1", "param3");
```

и почему?

Ответы на [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/570778/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-3-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9) смотрел, но не нашёл там ответа на свой.

Comment: Самый простой способ получить ответ - провести эксперимент ;)

Comment: @FoggyFinder согласен, но хочу теорию )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd264739.aspx)

Использование именованных и необязательных аргументов следующим образом влияет на разрешение перегрузки:

> 1. метод, индексатор или конструктор является кандидатом на выполнение, если каждый из его параметров является необязательным или
>      соответствует по имени или позиции одному аргументу в инструкции
>      вызова, а этот аргумент можно преобразовать к типу параметра;
> 2. если обнаружено более одного кандидата, правила разрешения перегрузки для предпочтительных преобразований применяются к
>      аргументам, которые заданы в явном виде. Опущенные аргументы для
>      необязательных параметров игнорируются;
> 3. если два кандидата оказываются одинаково подходящими, предпочтение
>      отдается кандидату, у которого нет необязательных параметров,
>      аргументы которых были опущены в вызове. Это последовательность
>      общего приоритета при разрешении перегрузки для кандидатов с меньшим
>      числом параметров.

мне кажется в вашем случае применяется второе правило, и будет вызван первый конструктор.

Comment: Да, верно, вызывается первый.