# Двусмысленность при передаче делегата в конструктор

Tags: c#

Имеется класс команды, в упрощенном виде выглядящий так :

```
public class Command
{

    public Command(int price, Action method)
    {
        method.Invoke();
    }
    public Command(int price, Func<int> method)
    {
        var id = method.Invoke();
    }
}
```

В конструкторе 1 принимающий `int` и `Action` - ссылку на метод который ничего не возвращает. В конструкторе 2 `Func<int>` - ссылку на метод который возвращает целое число. Так же у меня есть 2 метода, котрые могут передаваться в конструктор :

```
public void toDosome()
{

}
public int newId()
{
    return 100500;
}
```

Далее я создаю обьект и проблем не возникает :

```
var command = new Command(11, newId);
```

Однако если вместо `newId` окажется `toDosome` :

```
var commandTo = new Command(1211, toDosome);
```

Мне выпадет исключение :

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties.

При этом я не могу удалить какой либо конструктор, что бы успешно создавать `command` или `commandTo`. Как поступить в такой ситуации ?

Comment: Возвращаемый тип не является частью сигнатуры метода

Comment: Как сделать: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/570782/218063

Comment: Хм, а у меня проблема не воспроизводится, нормально компилируется и работает. Ага, в C# 6.0, 7.0, 7.1 и 7.2 не работает, но работает с C# 7.3!

Comment: Вот п.3 читайте: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-7.3/improved-overload-candidates.md Ошибки как бы нет, просто C# до 7.3 был недостаточно умен, чтобы отбросить метод, у которого не совпадает возвращаемый тип параметра-делегата.

Comment: вопрос интересный, почему он первое сжевал? Почему он отбросил Action, а явно выбрал Func

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov видимо только разработчики языка смогут дать точный ответ. кстати, почему вы удалили свой ? ведь он вполне рабочий

Comment: @Сергей удалил, потому что читал C# спецификацию 6.0 про Overload в поисках пояснения проблемы.. Но ничего конкретного не смог найти, чтобы объяснило это поведение полностью. Верну в качестве ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создавайте явно делегат типа Action, передавая целевую функцию делегату и проблема выбора перегрузки функции исчезнет

```
var commandTo = new Command(1211, new Action(toDosome));
```

Comment: минус, будьте добры, прокомментируйте пжлста.

Comment: я минус не ставил, как раз наоборот ).компилирует без ошибок, но хочется понять с чем было связано исключение.